# Getting the names separated into own columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that I need to separate the names into `first name` `middle name` and `last name` issue I am having is on some occasions people have two last/middle names or spaces creating
lager names.
This is a sample of what I have:

```
name 
John Smith 
Jack A Doe 
Jane Marie Jones Smith
```

I have found that doing `df[['firstname','middlename','middlename1','lastname']] = df['name'] .str.split(expand=True)` then just combining the middle names together with logic and this works but the issue I am having with this is if the  file I am using updates and a name like **Josh Jacob Jingle Hiemer Schmidt** then it will throw a ValueError saying: `Columns must be same length as key.` because I didn't accommodate for  someone with 5 names.  tried doing
`name_parts = df['name'].str.split(expand = True)`

`df['first_name'] = name_parts[0]`

`df['last_name] = name_parts.iloc[:,1]`

`df['middle_name'] = name_parts.iloc[:,1:-1].apply(lammba row:" ".join(row.dropna()),axis = 1)`

when I do this I only seem to get the last name. The desired output should look like this.

```
first_name       middle_name            last_name 
  John                                    Smith
  Jack                A                   Doe
  Jane           Marie Jones              Smith
  Josh          Jacob Jingle Hiemer       Schmidt
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, without regex:

```py
df["first_name"] = (tmp := df["name"].str.split()).str[0]
df["middle_name"] = tmp.str[1:-1].str.join(" ")
df["last_name"] = tmp.str[-1]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                     name first_name  middle_name last_name
0              John Smith       John                  Smith
1              Jack A Doe       Jack            A       Doe
2  Jane Marie Jones Smith       Jane  Marie Jones     Smith
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own function for splitting the name into first, middle and last. Then call your function using apply.

```
def get_name(x):
    data = x['name'].split()
    if len(data) == 1:
        return x, '', ''
    if len(data) == 2:
        return data[0], '', data[1]
    return data[0], ' '.join(data[1:-1]), data[-1]

df[['first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name']] = df.apply(get_name, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Output

```
                               name first_name          middle_name last_name
0                        John Smith       John                          Smith
1                        Jack A Doe       Jack                    A       Doe
2            Jane Marie Jones Smith       Jane          Marie Jones     Smith
3  Josh Jacob Jingle Hiemer Schmidt       Josh  Jacob Jingle Hiemer   Schmidt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/JpHAf9/1):

```
pat = r'(?P<first_name>[^\s]+)\s+(?:(?P<middle_name>.*)?\s)?(?P<last_name>[^\s]+)'
out = df['name'].str.extract(pat).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  first_name          middle_name last_name
0       John                          Smith
1       Jack                    A       Doe
2       Jane          Marie Jones     Smith
3       Josh  Jacob Jingle Hiemer   Schmidt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your original dataframe was initialised like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John Smith',
                            'Jack A Doe',
                            'Jane Marie Jones Smith',
                            'Josh Jacob Jingle Hiemer Schmidt']})  # etc
```

which outputs:

```
                               name
0                        John Smith
1                        Jack A Doe
2            Jane Marie Jones Smith
3  Josh Jacob Jingle Hiemer Schmidt
```

You can iterate through the list of names and split each name into a list of its parts (as you did with `name_parts = df['name'].str.split(expand = True)`)

You can then use Python list indexing and slicing to separate the list into its first value at `[0]`, last value at `[-1]` and values in between at `[1:-1]`

```
new_df = {'first_name': [],
          'middle_name': [],
          'last_name': []}

for name in df['name']:
    name_parts = name.split(" ")
    
    new_df['first_name'].append(name_parts[0])  # first part
    new_df['last_name'].append(name_parts[-1])  # last part
    
    middle_names = ' '.join(name_parts[1:-1])  # any parts in the middle
    new_df['middle_name'].append(middle_names)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
```

which ultimately outputs:

```
  first_name         middle_names last_name
0       John                          Smith
1       Jack                    A       Doe
2       Jane          Marie Jones     Smith
3       Josh  Jacob Jingle Hiemer   Schmidt
```

You can hide the indexes on the right when printing if you'd like with `print(df.to_string(index=False)`